# SharpDevelop equivalent of Visual Studio's "Break on exceptions"

Tags: .net, debugging, exception, sharpdevelop

In Visual Studio, there's a debugger setting labelled "Break on exceptions" or something like that.  It drops into the debugger whenever an exception is raised (that is, on the first pass of the two pass exception mechanics), regardless of whether the exception will be handled or not.

This is a very useful feature, and I try to keep it on all the time when running in the debugger as I prefer to never have any exceptions raised.

I can't find an equivalent setting in SharpDevelop.  Any idea whether it's there, and if not, why not?

Comment: If you are using .NET then your goal ** to never have any exceptions raised** is not really possible.  Microsoft chose to use Exception handling as a method of code flow control.  VS let you set the `break on thrown exception` on a per Exception class basis.  SD v4 only has a blanket option to pause on ALL exceptions, not just the specific ones you care about.  Still, it is better than nothing. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SD v4 they added "Pause on handled Exception", a checkbox in the "Tools / Options" dialog, in the "Debugging / General" section.

[image: SD v4 - Tools / Options / Debugging]

This will help you achieve your goal of **never have any exceptions raised**.
( as long as .NET doesn't choose to use Exception handling as a form of code-flow-control. )

**UPDATE**: In SD v5 they added the ability to choose which Exceptions to catch when thrown, whether handled or not.

[image: SD v5 - Tools / Options / Debugging]

And then you can enter the class name of the specific Exception you are interested in catching.  At any time you can come back and uncheck the entry if you are no longer interested in that type of exception.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Hmm.  I guess not:</strike>

http://bugtracker.sharpdevelop.net/issue/ViewIssue.aspx?id=1511&PROJID=4

Still, I wonder if there's a good reason that this isn't in there.  Is it hard to implement?

This feature was added in SharpDevelop 4.0. See [Jesse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31862880/24874).

Comment: Not at all. Well at least not using mdbg as a backend.

Comment: @DrewNoakes - Sadly, the link now just takes you to the "Issues" top.  They must have reorganized the DB. Can you find the new link? Was the issue resolved in the last 5 years?

Comment: @DrewNoakes - I see that in SD v4 there is `Tools / Options / Debugging / Pause on handled Exception` which is the resolution of the lost bug report.

Comment: @JesseChisholm, nice. Want to post an answer (a screenshot would be great too) and I'll accept it?

Comment: @DrewNoakes - and in SD v5 it lets you customize which exceptions to break on. :)

Comment: @DrewNoakes - I had to go get SD v5 so I could get the screen shot with the best answer to your needs. ;-) Thus the edit to my answer.